# react native - not receiving notification when app is killed/not started

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using [react-native-firebase@4.2.0](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) for push notifications.

When app is open on screen, I receive the notification via `onNotification` and an alert as intended by my code.

**PROBLEM 1**
When app is in background (not killed), I receive the notification in status bar but on tapping it, it just gets dismissed and app is not opened.

I also get this error in android logcat:

```
06-21 17:26:03.892  5926  8672 D RNFMessagingService: onMessageReceived event received
06-21 17:26:03.913  5926  8600 E ReactNativeJS: No task registered for key RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage
--------- beginning of crash
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mycustomapp, PID: 5926
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: No task registered for key RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage, stack:
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime: startHeadlessTask@57242:24
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime: __callFunction@4106:49
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@3876:31
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime: __guardSafe@4068:13
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime: callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@3875:21
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime: 
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:56)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:40)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
06-21 17:26:03.932  5926  8601 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
06-21 17:26:03.938   590   590 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for service=opdiagnose pid=5926 uid=10238 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:opdiagnose_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
06-21 17:26:03.939   590   590 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for service=opdiagnose pid=5926 uid=10238 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:opdiagnose_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
06-21 17:26:03.939  5926  8601 W OPDiagnose: getService:OPDiagnoseService NULL
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging: Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging: java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging:     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:570)
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging:     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging:     at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzb(Unknown Source:81)
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging:     at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzc(Unknown Source:2)
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging:     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source:353)
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging:     at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:26)
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging:     at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
06-21 17:26:03.946  5926  8672 W FirebaseMessaging:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

**PROBLEM 2**
When app is killed or not started, I receive this in my android logcat:

> W GCM     : broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent {
>   act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000
>   pkg=com.mycustomapp (has extras) }

and that's it. No push notification in status bar or anything.

These are the services added in my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />
```

functions invoked when the app starts:

```
firebase.messaging().hasPermission()
  .then(enabled => {
      if (enabled) {
          // permissions granted
      } else {
          // permissions not granted
      }
  });

firebase.messaging().getToken()
  .then(fcmToken => {
      if (fcmToken) {
          // user has a device token
          console.log(fcmToken);
      } else {
          // user doesn't have a device token yet
      }
  });

firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification()
  .then((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
      if (notificationOpen) {
          // App was opened by a notification
          // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
          // Get information about the notification that was opened
      }
  });

this.onTokenRefreshListener = firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh(fcmToken => {
  // Process your token as required
  console.log(fcmToken);
});

this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed((notification: Notification) => {
  // Process your notification as required
  // ANDROID: Remote notifications do not contain the channel ID. You will have to specify this manually if you'd like to re-display the notification.
  console.log("onNotificationDisplayed", notification);
});

this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification: Notification) => {
  // Process your notification as required
  Alert.alert(
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      [
          {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
      ],
      { cancelable: true }
  )
});

this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
  // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
  const action = notificationOpen.action;
  // Get information about the notification that was opened
  const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
  console.log("onNotificationOpened", notification);
});

this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message: RemoteMessage) => {
  // Process your message as required
  console.log("onMessage", message);
});
```

And this is my **bgMessaging.js**:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// Optional flow type
import type { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase';

export default async (message: RemoteMessage) => {
    // handle your message
    console.log("RemoteMessage", message);
    return Promise.resolve();
}
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('AppBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging);
```

If it is relevant at all, I use `react-native-navigation`. If you need any other information, please comment.

Answer (score 2):

> The headless task must be registered as RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage.

Change your code:

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('AppBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging);
```

To

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging);
```

I hope you have already completed [this 4 steps](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/messaging/receiving-messages#2)-Handle-background-messages) to list for FCM messages in the background.

Comment: Okay, this helped. Now I receive notifications when the app is in the background i.e. not killed. But when the app is killed/not started, this shows up in logcat: `GCM     : broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.mycustomapp (has extras) }` , but no notification is displayed. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can u generate signed apk and test it again? I think it is only happen in debug stage.

Comment: Tried. It's same as it was in debug. Should I add something under this function?: [Step 2] (https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/messaging/receiving-messages#2)-Handle-background-messages) for it to show a notification?

Comment: @KetanMalhotra what version of android are you using, in android pie I have the same issue, but it works fine in android 6.

Answer (score 1):

**Background & Kill state messages**

When the application is in a background or Kill state, the onMessage handler will not be called when receiving messages. Instead, you need to setup a background callback handler via the setBackgroundMessageHandler method.

To setup a background handler, call the setBackgroundMessageHandler outside of your application logic as early as possible:

> // index.js
> import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'; import
> messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'; import App from
> './App';
>
> // Register background handler
> messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
> console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage); });
>
> AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => App);

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding:

```
messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceived);
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(onMessageReceived);
```

in **index.js** instead of **App.js** and use **react-native-notify** library to show notification locally.

this is the complete code of my **index.js** for Firebase notification configuration.

```
import notifee, {AndroidImportance, EventType} from '@notifee/react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

async function onMessageReceived(message) {
const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
id: 'important',
name: 'Important Notifications',
importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
});
console.log('message received', JSON.stringify(message, null, 2));
try {
notifee.displayNotification({
title: message.notification.title,
body: message.notification.body,
android: {
channelId,
importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
},
});
} catch (e) {
console.log('error ....... push notification', e);
}
}

messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceived);
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(onMessageReceived);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Following article can give some reasons if everything is configured correctly.

> [Why your Push Notifications never see the light of day](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793/)

Answer (score -1):

To Show the notifications in the background also when the App listens to the notification from the firebase you have to create the local notification to display.

I will suggest to use the react-native-fcm library it is very easy to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fcm

Comment: react-native-fcm is retired